# CakePHP Auth doesn´t allow images to be displayed

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, authorization, fancybox-2

I have a gallery that was being displayed correctly but after I made the permissions using `Auth` the thumbnails no long display an image, but when i delete the `function beforFIlter()`, `public function isAuthorized($user)` and `Auth` component from `AppController`,it works somehow, how can this be fixed?
I am using CakePHP 2.4.4 and timthumb 2 and fancybox.

** AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
                            'Session','Auth' => array(
                                                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'admin_index'),
                                                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
                                                'authorize' => array('Controller')
                                                )
                        );

public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role']==='admin'){
        return true; //admin pode acedeer a  todas as actions
    }
    return false; // os outros utilizadores não podem
}
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','login');

}
public $helpers = array('Html' ,
                        'Form' ,
                        'Timthumb.Timthumb',
                        'Paginator', 
                        'Session',
                        'Js',
                        'Fancybox.Fancybox');   


}
```

**GalleriesController**

```
    public function ShowImages(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
        $gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);
    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
    }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Galeria</h2>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        //$src3 = 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        $this->Fancybox->setProperties( array( 
            'class' => 'fancybox3',
            'className' => 'fancybox.image',
            'title'=>'Single Image',
            'rel' => 'gallery1'
            )
        );
        $this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)));

        $this->Fancybox->setMainContent($src3);
        echo $this->Fancybox->output();
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```

[Error image1](http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h184/SunTzu1988/erros_auth_imagens_consola_zpse8381239.png)

[Error image2](http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h184/SunTzu1988/erros_auth_imagens_zps21a5cd1f.png)

Comment: Does your `GalleriesController` have a `beforeFilter()` callback defined as well? If so, make sure it properly invokes `parent::beforeFilter()`!

Comment: No there isn't a `beforeFilter()` in the controller, only actions to upload and delete images.

Comment: any debug message? Like Auth message?

Comment: No Auth message, but when debugging `$this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => '267px', 'height' => '189px')));` I get a `null` on every image, although when I click on the the link it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think found the solution.
Try doing this.

put debug mode to 0;
empty the timthumb folder.
refresh your page.

**EDIT** (moved from comments)

don't use `px`, this :

```
$this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , rray('width' => '267px', 'height' => '189px')));
```

should be :

```
$this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)));
```

**UPDATE**
Use the following lines on `TimthumbController class`. It will work like a charm.

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('image');
}//end of beforeFilter
```

Comment: I get : _Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred_.

Comment: I tried this here. In debug mode 2, if the Auth Component is loaded, the timthumb not work. But it works with Auth if the debug mode set to 0. Its may be a bug on timthumb.

Now you need to set debug mode to 2 and let us show the error..

Comment: Setting the debug to 2 and loading debug don't show any error message, also I tried with Auth loaded and debug mode set to 0 and it didn't work aswell.

Comment: @FazalRasel : shouldn't it be `array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)` since integer and Boolean values go without quotes?

Comment: I get _Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred._ again. When you say empty the Timthumb folder you mean the plugin or the _tmp_ folder?

Comment: timthumb under tmp folder.

Comment: I get a `500 (Internal Server Error) ` on every image, according to chrome console. Also I noticed that, while using the console, that on every image, Auth is trying to redirect them to the action `login` from  `UsersController`, wich is causing the error, I will update my question with a prtscreen of showing some.

Comment: And one more thing. I reported that issue on github. And they fixed it. You can try by redownload that plugin.

Comment: It is working now, many thanks to both @JFK and @Fazal Rasel. Thanks for your dedication to my issue. I had also to make a change on `AppController`, I had to place the `$this->Auth->allow('image');` in the before `beforeFilter` and it started working, after redownloading the plugin.